# How to link to the top of a list item within the same page?

Tags: html, hyperlink, html-lists

I tried to create `id`s for ordered list items in html and then refer to them within the same page as follows:

```
<ol>
<li  id="item1">
Insert text here
</li>

<br>

<li id="item2">
Insert text here
</li>
</ol>

<a href="#item1">Item 1</a>
<a href="#item2">Item 2</a>
```

However what ends up happening is that the anchors end up pointing to the bottom of the text within the items, instead of the item number. In other words, when I click on `Item 1`, `Item 2` is displayed instead.

My question therefore is, is there a way to link to the items so that the item linked to is actually displayed?

NOTE: I am editing text wihtin a text field (editor) on a [Moodle](https://docs.moodle.org/35/en/Main_page)-page, which might be the source of the problem.

Comment: Firstly you are missing a hashtag. The correct links would be

    <a href="#item1">Item 1</a>
    <a href="#item2">Item 2</a>

Without the hashtag the link is resolved as a url rather that an anchor you want

Comment: Sorry, I did have the hashtags in place, but forgot to include them in the sample here and the problem still remains. I fixed the question.

Comment: Can you be clearer on what you are asking? The anchor link always sends you to the top of the element of the anchor? I tried to recreate your html and everything works as expected.

Comment: Then it might be an issue with the fact that I'm editing text in html-mode within a text field in a [Moodle](https://docs.moodle.org/35/en/Main_page)-document, and the setting of the site somehow mess things up. I suppose this is relevant information and should probably update the question...

Comment: Can you attach the exactly link?

Comment: The issue is that I'm setting up a Moodle-page for a course, which requires authentication. Unless you happen to be a student or a member of staff at the university I work at, you will not be able to access the page.

Comment: Make a similar example here : https://codepen.io/ and post the link

Comment: Here is a link with the complete source code for the page: https://codepen.io/thesodesa/pen/wXzPyB. The links ("Tapa1" and "Tapa2") seem to work because I have linked to the previous elements on the page.

Comment: So what's the problem? :P

Comment: I guess I should aswer my own question then... :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the correct way to link them, in order to get the right result. As you want to link to an element on the same page you should use `<a href="#id"></a>`. 
Without the # it won't give you the desired result.

Comment: I did have the #s in place but forgot to include them in the question. It is now fixed, but the problem presists.

Answer (score 0):

An ugly fix to the problem seems to be to link to the elements preceding the desired targets. In this case, if I wanted to link to `item2`, I should link to `item1`, and in the case of `item1` the reference should be made to the preceding paragraph, which of course then needs to have its own `id`.